# VHDL And or Invert Circuit, Output undetermined for first 5 ns during simulation. Internal signals also not showing on waveform

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I am trying to show simulation results for a simple And or Invert circuit. I have been struggling to get to the bottom of this for a while now. The code compiles correctly although the simulation does not show the results I expected. The output signal shows as undefined for 5ns then shows a correct signal while the internal signals stated in my design do not show up at all during simulation.

Can anyone check my code for me? Thanks.

Design

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity AOI is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC;
           B : in STD_LOGIC;
           C : in STD_LOGIC;
           D : in STD_LOGIC;
           F : out STD_LOGIC);
end AOI;

architecture V1 of AOI is
begin

    F <= (A and B) nor (C and D);

end V1;

architecture V3 of AOI is
    signal I1, I2, I3 : std_logic;  
begin

    F <= not I3 after 1 ns;
    I3 <= I1 or I2 after 2 ns;
    I1 <= A and B after 2 ns;
    I2 <= C and D after 2 ns;
    
end V3;
```

Testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity andorinvertTB is
end;

architecture TB1 of andorinvertTB is
  
    component AOI_component
        port(A,B,C,D : in std_logic;
             F       : out std_logic);
    end component;
    
       signal A,B,C,D,F : std_logic;
    
    for G1: AOI_component use entity work.AOI(V3);

begin

    stimuli: process
    begin
        A <= '0'; B <= '0'; C <= '0'; D <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
        A <= '0'; B <= '1'; C <= '0'; D <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
        A <= '1'; B <= '0'; C <= '1'; D <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
        A <= '1'; B <= '1'; C <= '1'; D <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
        wait;
    end process;
    
    G1: AOI_component port map ( A=>A, B=>B, C=>C, D=>D, F=>F );
    
end;
```

[Image of simulation results - Output F undefined at the start and missing internal singals I1, I2 and I3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9dud.png)

Comment: You'd be able to see where the [5 ns delay on F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqnB.jpg) comes from if you had run your simulation after adding I1, I2, and I3 to the waveform display. The default initial values of A, B, C, and D are 'U'. The Assignments to I1 and I2 are scheduled for 2 ns from the current simulation time, The assignment to I3 for 2 ns after that and the assignment to F 1 ns later. Note the similar delay after 30 ns on I1, I2, i3 and F. Concurrent assignment statements are elaborated to requivalent processes whose sensitivity lists are signals evaluated on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you I was forgetting to rerun the simulation after adding the internal waveforms!